# Transaction Builder: Error Message: GS013

Tags: nft, gnosis-safe, error

I sent an nft to the wrong chain (eth) so I created a new wallet through the loom video on the correct chain (optimism). Now I am trying to send my nft from my newly created wallet on optimism with the same address as the eth wallet i sent it to but am getting this error message:

Error Message: GS013

require(success || safeTxGas != 0 || gasPrice != 0, "GS013");

I have eth in my wallet so not sure why gas issue is coming up?

I have tried just sending eth from this wallet but it says 'The Safe SDK could not be initialized.'

It seems that I am unable to use this newly created wallet for anything.

The tenderly link here shows more detail if needed: https://dashboard.tenderly.co/public/safe/safe-apps/simulator/ae1174ef-7084-4451-b423-fbbd309e2134

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message when importing your Safe in app.safe.global:

```
This Safe Account was created with an unsupported base contract. The web interface might not work correctly. We recommend using the command line interface instead.
```

- Could you give some info about where you created your Safe?
- Can you share the code when you are trying to initialize the SDK?